iperf3 test shows 40Gbps for a 100Gbps supported NIC
I was performing iperf3 tests between 2 servers which supports 100Gbps NIC.
OS is rocky linux 8.8 Both ports are LACP bonding enabled with layer 3+4 mode. Hardware is HPE alletra 4110.
Test1: Both servers connected to switch ports where they show 100Gbps on both switch and Server side. Max throughput is 40Gbps
Test2: Servers NIC ports are connected back to back and still shows 40Gbps throughput.
I did increase sysctl tuninng to increase the window size to 2G and so on.. Unfortunately they still report throughput of 40Gbps and less.
Am i missing some thing here.. Can i not achieve 100Gbps? Can someone guide?
Thanks.
